# Declare value as null if not found in $_POST when using $this->input->post()

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, post, form-submit

How should I handle cases where the key that I am trying to access in a POST submission is null or not found?

My current code:

```
$data = array(
    'harga_jual' => $this->input->post('harga_jual') == '' ? NULL : $this->input->post('harga_jual')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `post()` method in CodeIgniter's `Input` class will return a `null` value if the accessed element in your payload is not found (it defaults to `null`).

For this reason, you don't need to perform any additional operations in your script -- just enjoy the helper method's behavior.

You can see in the source code if you search for `function _fetch_from_array(` in your CI project.

```
$data = [
    'harga_jual' => $this->input->post('harga_jual')
];
```

If you are passing `$data` to the view and `$this->input->post('harga_jual')` was not submitted or was `null`, then `$harga_jual` will contain `null` in the view.

Answer (score -1):

or if your php version >= 7.0 you can use the Null Coalescing Operator from [this article](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php).

```
<?php
// Fetches the value of $_GET['user'] and returns 'nobody'
// if it does not exist.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// This is equivalent to:
$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';

// Coalescing can be chained: this will return the first
// defined value out of $_GET['user'], $_POST['user'], and
// 'nobody'.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? $_POST['user'] ?? 'nobody';
?>
```

Comment: This advice is not relevant (and is not recommended) within a CodeIgniter application.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the`null` in quotes. You can try the following-

```
$harga_jual = $this->input->post('harga_jual') ? $this->input->post('harga_jual') : 'null'; //you can use $_POST['harga_jual'] also

$data = array('harga_jual' => $harga_jual);
```

Comment: This answer is performing unnecessary actions.  See my answer to understand why this answer should not be used.

Answer (score -1):

You can use is_null() to check the POST value is null or not.

```
$data = array(
    'harga_jual' => is_null($this->input->post('harga_jual')) ? NULL : $this->input->post('harga_jual')
    );
```

Comment: This answer is performing unnecessary actions.  See my answer to understand why this answer should not be used.